# Problem with importing model. Points

Tags: import, obj

After importing obj file I get just unlinked points.
I have nice model in one hand
[image: How it looking on site]

And after importing .obj file in blender getting just a cloud of unlinked points
[image: Imported .obj file]

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to import the object not with "Wavefront(.obj)", but with "Wavefront(.obj) (legacy)"